# jquery hover similar to youtube buttons

Tags: jquery

```
 $(".post").hover(function(){
            $(".buttons input", this).show();

        });
```

What's the easiest way to make the same element hide again once mouse goes off .post? I' trying to make something similar to youtube posts (buttons are shown/hidden on mouse on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the markup

Based on assumption,

```
$(".post").hover(function(){
      $(".buttons input", this).fadeIn('slow');
},
function(){
 $(".buttons input", this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: Exactly that, thanks. Although I don't understand how it works.

Comment: The `.hover()` method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. It takes two functions as arguements, first one for `mouseenter` and second one for `mouseleave`. Refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)